# Two Internet Connections - One Network - How To Manage

Tags: networking, local-area-network

Here is my situation. Im not a network expert so sorry if I'm not explaining this correctly.

*In my company, we have two separate internet connections from different ISPs. Both the routers are connected to a Switch.*

*We have two windows servers (2019) for the proxy and the file server. (Assume there is no proxy server or firewall installed right now and suggest me a good proxy and a firewall for my purpose)*

*There are 65 client machines (running windows 7 & 10) on each floor of the company that has given static IPs (192.168.1.X). All three floors of the company have separate switches that connect client machines of each floor*

**What I want is to give access to a range of IPs to a certain ISP and limit their web accessibility through the proxy server or the firewall. Then give another range of IPs to the second ISP with some web filtering.**

Hope you understood the situation. Please help me to get a solution for this.

Comment: Let's see if I understand you:  You want one group to use the proxy for web browsing with ISP1, and a second group to not use a proxy for ISP2?

Comment: Umm, I want second group also to use proxy. But I want them to use the ISP2.

Answer (score 0):

This is fortunately not that hard to solve. Let's say we define the following:
ISP_A and ISP_B being your two ISPs and CLIENT_NET_A (192.168.1.0/24) and CLIENT_NET_B (192.168.2.0) being the two different subnets in your office. Then what you could do to achieve what you want is this:

- Set up a router that has an address on both CLIENT_NET_A and
  CLIENT_NET_B, say 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1.
- The router should also have connections to ISP_A and ISP_B. Not every router out there
  will do this nicely, but Mikrotik and many others will work for this kind
  of setup
- Setup NAT on the router so traffic going coming from CLIENT_NET_A goes to ISP_A and correspondingly for CLIENT_NET_B
- Still on the router, add a route from CLIENT_NET_A to CLIENT_NET_B if you
  want clients on the two subnets to able to communicate with each other
- Assign static IP addresses to the clients you want to be part of CLIENT_NET_A and CLIENT_NET_B, making sure to assign default gateway matching the correct subnet

You should probably also add a DHCP server to your setup so you can assign addresses to guests and you might even want to assign IPs to your clients via DHCP too - you would have to register each client's MAC address in the DHCP though.

With respects to the firewall, you might want to add a drawing to improve understanding of your setup.

That should cover it from a very top down view. If you need help with the specifics, you can easily find it online. While not entirely standard, your setup is not that different from a lot of other stuff out there.